# Reference Request for Convergence Rate of the 1D Poisson Equation with the Finite Element Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, poissons-equation

Consider the Poisson equation in 1D: $$-u_{xx} = f(x), \hspace{6mm} u(a) = d1, \hspace{2mm} u(b) = d2$$Assuming a uniform partition such that $x_n = a + nh$, where $h = (b-a)/N$ and $n \in [0,N]$. Im wondering if anyone has a reference I can use which derives or justifies the convergence rate of this problem for the finite element method?

Comment: What do you mean?  As $N\to\infty$ fixing a piecewise degree $k$?  Fix mesh and increase the polynomial degree?  Some other spline?  ...

Comment: @user10354138 Letting $N \to \infty$ using linear finite elements (linear basis functions).